# FFMPEG: how to add watermark to video?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, h.264, aac

My Platform: Ubuntu 10.10 + FFMPEG 0.5.3(I installed ffmpeg from source)

I try to add Watermark to a .MOV video with FFMPEG 0.5.3 `imlib2.so` (Please note FFMPEG 0.6+ dont support `imlib2.so`, so I use ffmpeg 0.5.3)

Here is my code:

`ffmpeg -sameq -i example.mov -vhook '/usr/local/lib/vhook/imlib2.so -x 0 -y 0 -i /var/www/files/watermark.png' newexample.mov`

Here is the output:

```
FFmpeg version 0.5.3, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-avfilter --enable-filter=movie --enable-avfilter-lavf
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  built on Jul  3 2011 12:05:08, gcc: 4.4.5

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (5994/100) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'example.mov':
  Duration: 00:03:14.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3350 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
    Stream #0.1(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1150x647, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
Output #0, mov, to 'newexample.mov':
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1150x647, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: 0x0000, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
Unsupported codec for output stream #0.1
```

What could be the possible problem? Is that AAC or H264 that is not supported?

I installed libavcodec-extra-52, linfaac, libfaad and etc. but the error is the same.

Do I have to install following this instruction?  [HOWTO: Install and use the latest FFmpeg and x264](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095) or there is a simpler solution?

Comment: If you fixed your own question, put the solution in an answer of its own.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski Where did he give any impression that he "fixed"/solved his own question?

Comment: @barlop: if you look at the revisions, you will see that he posted and update to his question which include an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this with recent ffmpeg is to use the overlay filter. The following command will place `watermark.png` on top of `input.mp4`, with the upper-left corner of the watermark fifteen pixels to the right and ten pixels down from the upper-left corner of the main video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=15:10[outv]' -map [outv] -map [0:a] \
-c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

Obviously, change 15 or 10 to whatever values you want.

There are also a few constants you may find useful, if you're putting watermarks on multiple videos with separate resolutions:

- W and H are the width and height of the main video (`input.mp4`)
- w and h are the width and height of the overlay video (`watermark.png`)

These can come in handy many times. For example, to place the watermark over the centre of the video, you could use:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[outv]'
```

Similarly, to centre the watermark over the upper-left sixth of the video:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/6:(H-h)/6[outv]'
```

For the lower-left sixth of the video:

```
'[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/6:(H-h)/(6/5)[outv]'
```

You can pretty much do whatever you need to.

See the [overlay filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) documentation for more information.

Comment: FYI: the "-map [0:a]" fragment results in "Output with label '0:a' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere." error using migw64 terminal 
 with ffmpeg.exe on Win10. Instead "-map 0:a" did the trick.